# Groupby Rolling counts filtered by condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, rolling-computation

I have dataset with a list of transactions in this format:

| transaction_ID | card_number | transaction_datetime | amount | store |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 2023-06-24 12:20:24 | 100.0 | A |
| 2 | 456 | 2023-08-27 23:12:00 | 250.0 | B |
| 3 | 123 | 2023-09-02 09:00:03 | 416.12 | A |
| 4 | 123 | 2023-09-02 10:30:03 | 6580.0 | C |

I have created a function by doing some research online that counts for each transaction, how many transactions has that card made in a specific time range, for example in the last hour, 3 days or 6 months:

```
def rolling_count(df, freq):
    return (df.set_index(transaction_datetime)
            .groupby("card_number")["card_number"]
            .rolling(freq, closed="left")
            .count()
            .fillna(0)
            .values
```

I then use the function like this:

```
df["number_transactions_lastday"] = rolling_count(df, "1D")
```

I now need to create other features that take into account the store as well. So instead of counting all the transactions that were made with that card in the past, to just count the ones that were made on the same store.

I have seen many examples online on how to add some conditions to these type of operations but none of the solutions work on my case.

How can I add a new column to my dataframe that does rolling counts while checking if the store is the same or not?

Example:

Input:

`df["number_tr_store_last6m"] = rolling_count_store(df, "180D") # so 6 months`

Expected output table:

| transaction_ID | card_number | transaction_datetime | amount | store | number_tr_store_last6m |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 2023-06-24 12:20:24 | 100.0 | A | 0 |
| 2 | 456 | 2023-08-27 23:12:00 | 250.0 | B | 0 |
| 3 | 123 | 2023-09-02 09:00:03 | 416.12 | A | 1 |
| 4 | 123 | 2023-09-02 10:30:03 | 6580.0 | C | 0 |

My database is quite large, so the code needs to be optimized the best as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see the below solution. You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function which allows and pass multiple arguments for calculations.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta


data = {
    "transaction_ID": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "card_number": [123, 456, 123, 123],
    "transaction_datetime": [
        "2023-06-24 12:20:24",
        "2023-08-27 23:12:00",
        "2023-09-02 09:00:03",
        "2023-09-02 10:30:03",
    ],
    "amount": [100.0, 250.0, 416.12, 6580.0],
    "store": ["A", "B", "A", "C"],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["transaction_datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(
    df["transaction_datetime"], format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"
)


def calculate_num_tr_store(row, days, df):
    start_date = row["transaction_datetime"] - timedelta(days=days)
    return len(
        df[
            (df["transaction_datetime"] > start_date)
            & (df["transaction_datetime"] < row["transaction_datetime"])
            & (df["store"] == row["store"])
        ].index
    )


df["number_tr_store_last6m"] = df.apply(calculate_num_tr_store, days=180, df=df, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
transaction_ID  card_number  ... store  number_tr_store_last6m
0               1          123  ...     A                       0
1               2          456  ...     B                       0
2               3          123  ...     A                       1
3               4          123  ...     C                       0

[4 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tested it on a sample of my data and it worked. However, when I tried running it for the whole database (with millions of entries) it's taking too long to run - in fact I haven't managed to get the final result yet.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to do it by changing a bit my original function:

```py
    def rolling_count(df, freq):
        result = df.set_index(transaction_datetime)
                   .groupby(["card_number", "store"])["store"]
                   .rolling(freq, closed="left")
                   .count()
                   .fillna(0)
        result.index = result.index.droplevel(1)
        result = result.sort_index()
        return result
```

It should be easily to adapt in case anyone needs to use for their case. My data has millions of rows and it takes around 3 min to run.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).